# Blocking HTTP requests without Host header using mod_security2

Tags: apache2, security

In my Apache configuration, I want to allow only Host header based vhosts. That is, I'd like to block any traffic by IP address only. I have mod_security2 installed, but I am only using the default rule set. Is mod_security2 the best place to configure this, and if so, how?

Apache 2.4.7, Ubuntu 14.04, PHP 5.5.9

Comment: Could you post apache and ubuntu version?

Comment: Updated question. Apache 2.4.7, Ubuntu 14.04, PHP 5.5.9

Comment: If you defined Name based Virtual hosts, try disabling default site with `sudo a2dissite default` or comment all directive inside virtualhost defined in '/etc/apache2/sites-available/default.conf'. After restart your apache.

Comment: @Letizia if i disable the default site, then access my server by IP, one of the name-based sites comes up

Comment: yes, in fact it was my doubt, what about comment directive inside default virtual host?

Comment: I think its because my vhosts are all <VirtualHost *:80>

Comment: Did you define your vhost like [Name based Virtual host](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/name-based.html)?

Comment: Yes, the sites all respond fine as name-based. That's not my issue. I simply want to stop the server from responding by IP only.

Comment: Okey, try to comment all directive in default virtual host so it would be like `<VirtualHost *:80> </VirtualHost>`. It is the first defined and so if apache doesn't match any vhosts, it will use this one and because of missing `DocumentRoot` it will result (I'm not sure) in 404 Not found. If you prefer 403 Forbidden, try insert `Require All Denied`

Comment: No that still serves up the next alphabetical enabled host in sites-enabled.

Comment: I found this [link](http://serverfault.com/questions/241704/blocking-non-virtual-host-access-in-apache). I'm not sure that you are right :) but I can't exec test now.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `<Directories>` chapters in your httpd.conf wherever you want it to apply (e.g. the /var/www and /var/www/html chapters on the default config)

```
 <RequireAll>
    Require expr ( -n %{HTTP_HOST} && %{HTTP_HOST} != "1.2.3.4" )
 </RequireAll>
```

-n matches "not empty" and the rest matches a Host: header not equal to your server's IP. You might need to repeat the second half with your public and internal IP, depending on your web routing setup.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to read my answer of the question [I need rules to drop some malicious Apache](https://askubuntu.com/q/922085/566421), where is explained how to download and configure [`OWASP ModSecurity Core Rule Set 3.x`](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/owasp-modsecurity-crs/blob/v3.2/dev/rules/REQUEST-920-PROTOCOL-ENFORCEMENT.conf).
However, here is simple example of the rule that you are asking for:

```bsh
# Deny requests without a host header
#
SecRule &REQUEST_HEADERS:Host "@eq 0" \
    "id:160, phase:2, log, drop, deny, status:403, \
        tag:'requests-without-host-header'"
```

The most important thing in the above rule is the parameter [`phase:2`](https://malware.expert/modsecurity/processing-phases-modsecurity/), thus the access will be denied before the response, but you will be able to white-list the rule at certain circumstances (if you need that) on `phase:1`. You can use `nolog`, also the final result of `drop`, `deny` and `status:403` is almost identical and you can decide to leave only one of these three arguments.

Checkout rule `id:160` in my repository [`pa4080/www-security-assistant`](https://github.com/pa4080/www-security-assistant/blob/master/file-system/etc/modsecurity/wwwsas-rules.conf.example) for more complex example. Also you may want to read the section `Missing/Empty Host Header` in [`REQUEST-920-PROTOCOL-ENFORCEMENT`](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/owasp-modsecurity-crs/blob/v3.2/dev/rules/REQUEST-920-PROTOCOL-ENFORCEMENT.conf) from [`SpiderLabs/owasp-modsecurity-crs 3.x`](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/owasp-modsecurity-crs).