# Auto add rule to IPTables in Specific case

Tags: iptables

I'm trying to build a simple Anti-DDoS for a game using IPTables. I don't know from where to start and just my question now is:

Assume that i'am using Ubuntu, I need to make a script or program (i don't really know what to call it) that in some cases after some checks for the coming packets it will add a rule to IPTables automatically for sometime and it will be removed after time also that i define. In other words like Auto-Filter i need to build.

For this which programming language i should learn to start my project?

Please give me examples if you can. Thanks.

Comment: Time ago I've wrote [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/922144/566421), that could give you some ideas. Unfortunately I think your question is too broad. You should be more specific.

Comment: Simply here is an example, Always check coming packets and if found a packet contain some hex-string then place a filter to drop this packets and this iptable rule will stay for sometime like 1 day and after it the rule removed.

Comment: You mean something like [How to block DDoS attacks on server with Steam](https://forums.alliedmods.net/showthread.php?t=106378) :)

Comment: This man will put a normal rules... I don't need it like that i mean how i can make checks for every packet input to my server and for some cases if the packet contain something i already defined so a rule is added for sometime and it will be removed after this time elapsed. Hope you get me. This what i try to do i don't know with which program language i should start.