# open source and free to use ddos attacks prevention solutions

Tags: 16.04, server, security

Not all hosting providers offer DDoS protection. In my case I would probably need to find myself a solution for my `VPS` against this kind of attacks.

I read [a useful documentation](https://www.globalsign.com/en/blog/how-to-prevent-a-ddos-attack-on-a-cloud-server/) with a list of open source DDoS prevention systems. 
Not considering those that are not free to use like `FastNetMon`, or those that seem specifically designed for Apache, like `NGINX` (I am not using Apache but Puma as a Ruby gem for a Ruby on Rails web application), or again that are primarily meant to monitor ssh connections, like `fail2ban`, I am considering to try `ddos-deflate` or `HAProxy`.

For [HAProxy](http://www.haproxy.org/) there are updated deb packages, however it is not a mere protection against DDoS, but a more complex piece of software with many functions. 
[ddos-deflate](https://github.com/jgmdev/ddos-deflate) is specifically designed to block a denial of service attack, having however at first glance a slower development pace than `HAProxy` (I counted one maintainer and one contributor), and a less responsive or active support service.

I wonder if any of you have experience with either `HAProxy` or `ddos-deflate` and would like to share points of view or suggestions.

Comment: I think [**this answer**](https://askubuntu.com/a/922144/566421) would be interesting for you.

Comment: Hello! May I ask why you mentioned FastNetMon as not free solution? FastNetMon Community edition is open source and completely free tool: https://github.com/pavel-odintsov/fastnetmon It works on almost all Linux distributions, almost all kernel versions and even works on non-x86 architectures like ARM or PowerPC. Also, you could find official Debian packages with FastNetMon: https://packages.debian.org/sid/fastnetmon