# Can hackers inject anything to the server outside /var/www/html

Tags: apache2, security, hacking

We got hack because of a bad security on our server. The hacker got access of the database probably from a php file holding database credentials in the html folder. The /var/www/html folder had root privileges and 777 permissions. 
Could the hacker have had injected anything outside the /var/www/html folder? Do we have to reset our server, or proper security would do?

**Note** that we already changed permissions and ownership of the html folder and files inside. We also changed the database credentials and implemented some MySQL security. Also blocked all ports except for the http, https and ssh port (change the ssh port as well)

Comment: There's never a way to be sure. Nuke the server from the orbit and reinstall if you had backup or start over again.

Comment: It depends how they got access to the server. Maybe they managed to discover some user's password that has sudo access. In that case, I would assume the worst.

Comment: It is not right on the topic, but here are presented few ideas about Apache's security improvement: [I need rules to drop some malicious Apache connection](https://askubuntu.com/a/922144/566421)

Comment: seems the only way they got there is from the permissions, there were no other sudo users than root and we didnt have a backup. Since there was no backup, its gonna be a pain to reconfigure everything that's why I need to if they were able to get past the html folder. What do u think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using a basic Apache2 setup, all `apache2` processes and PHP code executed was ran as the user:group `www-data:www-data` which limits where it can write data. An attacker would likely have access to:

- Your SQL databases since the credentials very likely had to be stored somewhere `www-data` could read, otherwise your web-app (eg. Wordpress) wouldn't be capable of connecting to your database.
- Any files in your `/home/*` directories, except files where permissions were `600` or similar, such as SSH keys. This means an attacker wouldn't have access to your SSH keys under most circumstances.
- Any API tokens ore other files stored in `/var/www/html`
- Any configuration files in `/etc` that didn't have restricted permissions. It's worth noting that `/etc/letsencrypt/live` has restricted permissions and cannot be read via `www-data` so your SSL keys should be safe.

In any case I would suggest distrusting any credentials on the system, such as SSH keys, API tokens and issuing new SSL certificates to be safe. You can so do a `find / -group www-data` to see any files created by `www-data` since there could be some random areas writable such as `/tmp`, places PHP sessions are stored, `/var/run`, etc.